# ListView [VirtualMode] change selected index

Tags: c#, listview, virtualmode

```
VirtualMode = true
MultiSelect = false
```

I can get selected index item, but how change it?

`SelectedIndices` is readonly.

Comment: That's what I did:
Set OwnDraw, add use internal var int (selectIndex).
On operation add/del item and SelectedIndexChanged I change selectIndex.
And in DrawSubItem use selectIndex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if you've found a solution, but I was having the same problem and just came up with this:

```
listView1.SelectedIndices.Clear();
listView1.SelectedIndices.Add(indexToSelect);
```